# Why did Benioff or Weiss say Dickon was older than Sam?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the Inside the Episode of S08E01, the showrunners (David Benioff and D. B. Weiss) said:

> ... Yet Sam's older brother was not a bad person,...

[image]

Sam is actually the older brother.

**Why did they say this?**

Comment: Presumably they just slipped up in the commentary?

Comment: Maybe Sam will turn out to have had an older brother, who hasn't been mentioned yet.

Comment: I'm surprised people are watching those commentaries... I cringe watching them seeing how 0 f's the writers give at this point. They're just focused on the spinoffs.

Comment: Did they both say it? Simultaneously? These *Inside the Shows* are weird.

Comment: …While D&D kinda forgot that Sam was sent to the Wall to make way for his younger brother to become the heir…

Answer (score 17):

**They misspoke**.

Samwell Tarly does not have an older brother. His younger brother, Dickon, is pictured in the screen shot.

Here is the link to [Game of Thrones' Inside the Episode summary](https://youtu.be/ha8Qsx6_OBw?t=257) posted to Youtube, on the part where they talk about Dickon.  Full quote:

> Yet Sam's older brother was not a bad person, and died, really, quite bravely, standing by his father's side.

They are clearly talking about Dickon, Sam's younger brother.

For evidence regarding Sam being the oldest brother we can look to the [Tarly dinner conversation](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=27415) in Season 6 Episode 6, provided by @user568458:

> (RANDYLL points to a blade mounted on a mantle beside the table.)
>
> **Randyll**: It's called Heartsbane. It's been in our family for 500 years. It's Valyrian steel. Only a handful of them left in the world. **It's supposed to go to my firstborn son after I die. To him. He will never wield that sword. If he were to become Lord Tarly of Horn Hill, it would be the end of this house.** I took you for a Mole's Town whore when I saw you and I made my peace with that. Who else would have him? But I overestimated him. No. It was a wildling whore that seduced my son. This you getting back at me, boy?

To clarify the text for those who are not familiar with Randyll's feelings for Sam - he is drilling into Sam and Gilly with his eyes as he says this, Sam looking less than thrilled.  The conversation is very much about Sam, Randyll Tarly's firstborn disappointment.